# ClassNotFoundException on Marshal.load

Tags: serialization, scala, marshalling, unmarshalling, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to do a marshal dump and load in Scala...

```
import scala.util.Marshal

case class Test(test: String)

val t = Test("hello")
val bytes = Marshal.dump(t)
Marshal.load[Test](bytes)
```

...but the call to Marshal.load is throwing a ClassNotFoundException...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1461)
at java.io.Ob...
```

I've also tried using the fully qualified class name but with no luck.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your code works just fine in Scala 2.8.1.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't here for me -- on Windows. Maybe it doesn't work on Windows for some reason? If so, a ticket might be in order.

Comment: @Daniel I tested it on Linux.

Comment: I tested the code under Linux, too.  It works when I compile the code via scalac and run it with scala, but it does not work when I put the code directly into the interpreter.  Did you use the interpreter for testing, scttnlsn?

Comment: Even when I copy & paste the code into the REPL it works as expected.

Comment: I've tried running the code both in the interpreter and by first compiling it with SBT (on OS X).  I just noticed that SBT is compiling for 2.8.1 but running on 2.7.7 so I tried manually compiling with scalac and running (2.8.1) and it worked!  I cannot get it to run in the interpreter despite which version I am using.

Comment: Any ideas why it won't work on 2.7.7?

Comment: Works with 2.9.1 running in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Which version of SBT are you using? I had similar problems with SBT 0.7.7 and resolved them by adding the following to my build:

```
// cause the SBT "run" action to fork                                                                                                              
override def fork = Some(new ForkScalaRun() {
  override def scalaJars = Seq(buildLibraryJar.asFile, buildCompilerJar.asFile)
})
```

Causing the "run" action to fork seems to resolve class loader problems, and problems with trapping `System.exit` calls:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Forking

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningProjectCode

Comment: for newer versions of sbt use `fork in run := true` in your `build.sbt`